# How to know the file is modifed in linux

Tags: c, linux

I want to know what system call is used in linux C programming is used to know whether a file is modified. 
I know that make utility compiles the file using the modification dates only. 
I want know how to find whether the file is modified or  not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Modified in relation to what? I'm afraid you will have to build your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`md5sum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) or [`sha1sum`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum) will hash the contents of the file, which should give you a better indication of actual changes than modification dates.

Comment: Im using md5sum to get exactly to know whether file is modified or not. But there is no ready function avaliable in C lanugage to give the md5sum. Im using system("md5sum file >> /tmp/md5sum.dat") then reading file for the value.

Answer (score 2):

[`stat(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/stat.2.html) gives you file times and more.

#### Edit 0:

You can look into [`fcntl(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fcntl.2.html) and `F_NOTIFY` flag - you'd have to open the directory, not the file itself though. Or the newer Linux [`inotify(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facility.

Comment: Ya i wil get the file time, but I want to whether the file is been modified or not..

Comment: No, it will not tell you if the file contents have actually changed.

Comment: I have to read a configuration file in a daemon, if there is any change in the configuration file done, then I have to perform some actions. So I thought to find whether the file is changed or not.  fcntl could have been perfect if the notification is on a file instead of a directory.

Comment: `inotify` would be one reasonable solution, but just using `stat` and checking the modification time is also fine.

Comment: stat is fine only when we know the previous time so that we can compare the modification time and say that file is modified. From stat even if I know that file is modified from a bit or other source my problem is solved. If I use stat I have keep the modified time in a file next time when I read the file again I have to check the stored date and find itz modified or not. I want to avoid all this circus and use the kernel features.

Comment: Keeping last modification time is much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ls` and various flags on it, like -l or -t and pipe to `grep` or something.  That will tell you when the last file was modified.  But it doesn't really tell you *if* the file was modified.  I think the only real way you can know that is if you are keeping track of when the last time it was modified in general (like checking from backups or something).